# Rebus with a Twist

Tags: riddle, visual, rebus

There is an 8-letter word hidden in this rebus. 
 The rebus is a riddle.

**What is the 8 letter word?**

[image: rebusrebus]

---

**EDIT: THAW should be TAHW, sorry 'bout that**

Comment: Flooding, thats what rain and thaw bring;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What goes up when the rain comes down?

It is an:

> Umbrella

---

Explanation

> *WHAT* is written bottom-to-top, *RAIN* is written top-to-bottom. That is the rebus itself.
>
>  The riddle itself is a chestnut.

Edit - interesting question raised by Preet in the comments, as

> The first word is WAHT (or THAW) and not WHAT (or TAHW).

Comment: So, it should be what instead of waht?

Comment: Ha ha, nice spot, I saw what I wanted to see, not what was actually in the image! Let's see "waht" the OP says 

Comment: Lol, nice answer though +1;)

Comment: Oh noes, did not notice that mistake :/

Comment: Haha does'nt matter ever the answerer didn't notice;)

Comment: Because of the error, I was stuck trying to make "What is *mixed* when the rain falls?" work. :/

Comment: @noedne That's exactly what I was thinking! I came to the same conclusion as Phylyp at first, but I realized it did not say what.

Comment: There might be an interesting riddle of its own there, @noedne :-) For me, I spent an undue amount of time puzzling over the 'H' shape formed by the rebus.

Comment: So all three of you win for closer attention to detail!